# How can you get Angular to regenerate parts of page after data is changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Simply put:

My Angular app parses through a JSON object of objects of objects using `ng-repeat` and some `ng-show`s, etc. It makes a nice layout on the page with all the data. In my page, the JSON objects (at any level) can be updated by the user.

The problem is, that after the data is updated, the layout doesn't regenerate itself. Instead, it just places in the new data in an ugly unformatted way.

How do you get the view to update as if you just loaded the page fresh with all this data there?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a `$scope.apply` issue.

You can manually apply changes to your scope via `$scope.apply()` which will re-render the changes to the page (not in a page-blink manner, but a typical Angular manner).

Often, this needs to be done when a change occurs via non-Angular JavaScript manipulating the data or the DOM itself, so check for areas in your script where that may be occurring as your culprit.